# Eloquent many-to-many with filters on both sides

Tags: orm, filter, many-to-many, laravel, eloquent

I've been reading the docs but I"m not sure how to do this. http://doc.laravelbook.com/eloquent/#many-to-many

Say I have a users, roles, and a pivot table.
I have `belongsToMany` set up for both Role and User

In a controller, I want to get a user_id and return what roles they have of a specific type only.
(There is also a role type table, but I can work with the IDs directly).

I start something like this

```
 $specific_type_role = Role::where('role_type_id', 3)::where(?$user_id?)

 //need to involve
 $circle_users = RoleUser::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

but I think it should be able to be done automatically. don't know how to include the filter right in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's that what you need but, you probably will be able to do something like that:

```
public function getAdminRoles()
{

    $user = User::find(1);

    return $user->roles()->where('role_type_id', 1)->get();

}
```